# php multidimensional array sort by key with exceptions

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am trying to sort a multidimensional array by its keys with exceptions to the sort.  I know that I can use `array_multisort(array_column ...` to sort by multiple columns but my issue is that my sort is more by type than it is by alphanumeric or numerical.

An example of the multidimensional array that I am working with is below:

```
[
 0 ['woid'=>17642-1,'schedule'=>'URGENT']
 1 ['woid'=>17643-1,'schedule'=>'ASAP']
 2 ['woid'=>17643-2,'schedule'=>'ASAP']
 3 ['woid'=>17644-1,'schedule'=>'JAN']
 4 ['woid'=>NC323-1,'schedule'=>'URGENT']
 5 ['woid'=>NC324-1,'schedule'=>'ASAP']
]
```

What I want is to have this sorted by key=`woid` starting with 'NC' at the top sorted ASC, then sort the remaining by key=`schedule` with the following order:

```
URGENT
JAN
FEB
MAR
APR
MAY
JUN
JUL
AUG
SEP
OCT
NOV
DEC
ASAP
```

all while retaining an ASC sort on the key=`woid`

I understand this may be confusing.  Below is an example of the desired outcome with the array example above:

```
[
 0 ['woid'=>NC323-1,'schedule'=>'URGENT']
 1 ['woid'=>NC324-1,'schedule'=>'ASAP']
 2 ['woid'=>17642-1,'schedule'=>'URGENT']
 3 ['woid'=>17644-1,'schedule'=>'JAN']
 4 ['woid'=>17643-1,'schedule'=>'ASAP']
 5 ['woid'=>17643-2,'schedule'=>'ASAP']
]
```

If more information is needed or a larger example I am more than happy to take the time and provide it.

Comment: I don't even know where to begin with the exceptions and I am not sure how to have an ASC sort on top of an ASC sort meaning `NC1, NC2, NC3, 1, 2, 3`.  I am only familiar with traditional sorting which would yield `1, 2, 3, NC1, NC2, NC3` for ASC and `NC3, NC2, NC1, 3, 2, 1` for DESC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use `usort` for multiple sort criteria like this.

For your `usort` comparison function, after you've figured out whether each `woid` starts with 'NC', you can compare the results of that check mathematically, then use the order from your custom sort array, and finally use `strcmp` to break ties.

```
$order = ['URGENT','JAN','FEB','MAR','APR','MAY','JUN',
          'JUL','AUG','SEP','OCT','NOV','DEC','ASAP'];

$order = array_flip($order);

usort($array, function($a, $b)  use ($order) {
    $aNC = strpos($a['woid'], 'NC') === 0;
    $bNC = strpos($b['woid'], 'NC') === 0;
    return ($bNC - $aNC)
        ?: ($order[$a['schedule']] - $order[$b['schedule']])
        ?: strcmp($a['woid'], $b['woid']);
});
```

In the first comparison, `$aNC` and `$bNC` will be booleans, but will be converted to ints (0 or 1) for the subtraction. If that comparison returns 0 (meaning both or neither `woid` value starts with 'NC'), the second comparison will be evaluated.

In the second comparison, the position of the two `schedule` values in the `$order` array is subtracted. If that comparison returns 0, (meaning both `schedule` values are the same), the third comparison will be evaluated.

In the third comparison, `strcmp` is used to return <0, 0, or >0 depending on the string comparison of the two `woid` values.

[Working Demo at 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/WDD69)

Comment: Sorry for all the edits. I kept rereading the question and noticing other criteria I'd missed.

Comment: No worries I appreciate the quick response.  I am getting an odd return.  The returned array is sorting by the schedule key but seems to be ignoring the woid key.NC and 17 seems to be mixed together throughout instead of NC on top and everything else sorted by schedule with ASC woid. usort is new to me so I am still trying to digest what you sent me to try other things.

Comment: @CraigHowell I added a bit more explanation of the sort criteria and a link to a working demo.

Comment: That link is definitely working as expected and returning the desired outcome.  I will have to dig into this further on my end to figure out why it is not working in my production.

Comment: Figured out the issue and it was on my end.  All set and works exactly expected.  Thanks for taking the time to help me out and teach me something new!